# I am getting incorrect URL in anchor tag

Tags: php, href

I've this line of code. I'm trying to point my link on google for testing.

```
$content.="<a href='google.com' target=_blank>".$webSites['value']."</a>";
```

Instead of getting 'google.com' only, I'm getting as given below: (http://192.168.10.126/consumer/google.com).

Comment: You cannot give links like `google.com`.. You have to give it as `http://www.google.com`

Answer (score 5):

Add `http://` in front of `google.com`

So your code looks like this:

```
$content.="<a href='http://google.com' target=_blank>".$webSites['value']."</a>";
```

Without `http://`, your browser thinks that `google.com` is an internal link. Adding the `http://` protocol lets the browser know you want to link to an external site.

Comment: that worked. But google is just for testing. Im working with dynamic sites. how bout sites with https on its url?

Comment: You can just use `https://` Basically just use the protocol (ftp, http, https, etc` and put `://` in front, then the web address! @Clem

Answer (score 4):

```
$content.="<a href='http://google.com' target=_blank>".$webSites['value']."</a>";
```

This should fix it. The reason is that your browser does not know that you're linking to an external resource, thus thinking that you're linking to a relative path. With adding http:// you force your browser to think that it's an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Just add http:// in front of google.com

current:

```
$content.="<a href='google.com' target=_blank>".$webSites['value']."</a>";
```

New:

```
$content.="<a href='http://google.com' target=_blank>".$webSites['value']."</a>";
```